# HammerJS event properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I'm developing this small website : [Website](http://rolandgroza.me) ; and I'm using HammerJS as a touch support library.

It seems to be responding to the events, and it recognizes the `event.type` property, but when I'm trying to get the `event.direction` or other related properties to the `drag` event nothing is output in the console ( I'm logging the results in the console ).

This is how I listen for the `drag` event "

```
Application.ApplicationController.prototype.Drag = function(selector, delay, callback) {
    return $(selector).on('drag', _.debounce(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        return (typeof callback === 'function' && callback !== undefined) ? callback.apply( event, [ event ] ) : 'Argument : Invalid [ Function Required ]';
    }, delay)); 
};
```

I'm calling it something like :

```
this.Drag(selector, delay, function(event) {
    console.log(event.type, event.direction);
});
```

Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong in there or if I'm missing something ?

**EDIT :** I have just replaced the jQuery library : [jquery.specialevents.hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.specialevent.hammer.js) ; with the old [jquery.hammer.js](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/jquery.hammer.js) ; and it seems like now it's responding to all events and I get all the properties I should. Still I would like to know why isn't the one I tried to work with working ?

**EDIT :** I have found the underlying cause of my issue, my code depends on some libraries which I'm loading asynchronous with the Yepnope script loader, so somewhere along the way instead of loading all the libraries ( including the jquery plugin for hammer.js ), some of them are lost :) I have fixed that issue and now the events have the properties that they're supposed to.

Comment: I'm getting a logged value for `event.type` but undefined for `event.direction`

Comment: that's exactly what I'm getting ... and that is why I asked here :)

Comment: All that means to me is that your code works fine, event objects just don't have direction properties.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.hammer()` to your method chain before you use `.on`? As in `$(selector).hammer().on(...`

Comment: I'm using the jQuery plugin, that's why I'm using `.on()`, but yes I have also tried the vanilla js way to ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22464/hammerjs-event-properties-are-undefined)

Comment: Just commented in the chat @asad :)

Comment: Found my error :) Somewhere along the way, where I'm loading the libraries async, I lost the jquery lib and I only had the vanilla js one :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Still I would like to know why isn't the one I tried to work with working ?

Understanding the difference between `jquery.specialevent.hammer.js` and `jquery.hammer.js` should help understand the problem. [Damien, the creator of `jquery.specialevent.hammer.js`, explains why](http://damien.antipa.at/2012/06/11/hammer-js-with-native-jquery-events/).

> However Eight Media decided to create their own namespace in jQuery to
>   activate the events.
>
> ```
> $("#element").hammer({ /* options */ }).on("tap", function(ev) { 
>     console.log(ev); 
> });
> ```
>
> So in the end they are not using the default
>   jQuery eventing system. That means my existing source code which used
>   jQuery mobile events has to be change. That’s why I decided to
>   implement the use of Hammer.JS with the jQuery special eventing API.
>
> ```
> $("#element").on("tap", { /* options */ }, function(ev) {
>     console.log(ev); 
> });
> ```
>
> I put jquery.specialevent.hammer.js onto my
>   Github where you can also find a demo. Maybe Eight Media accepts my
>   pull request and it will be part of Hammer.JS.

Comment: ~ As described in the question description, I have found the problem that was causing the described behavior. Also, I have read the reason why the `jquery.specialevent.hammer.js` has been introduced into the project :) Anyways, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 5):

`event.gesture.direction` should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Still, thought it might help others - I was searching for the event.direction issue for a couple hours.